# mysql displays TWO attributes from each FIVE tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have 5 tables in the topic of **telco management**:

1. Customer (`custID`, `cFname`, `contractID`, etc.)
2. Contract (`contractID`, `Duration`, `productCode`)
3. plan (`productCode`, `planType`, `price`)
4. billing (`billNo`, `custID`, `productCode`, `status` (eg; `pending` / `settle`))
5. product (`productCode`, `productName`, `productDescription`)

This query is to find the **cust ID** and **customer name** which in contract for 5 months and is using WirelessInternet plan that only at RM59/month. It also needs to display the pending billing status from customer. Please **show 2 attibutes from each five table.**

Please help me. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: have you worked or tried or this is home work ?

Comment: i've tried but the result is not as i want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

```
    select custID,cFname from Customer cust,Contract cont,plan p,billing b 
    where cust.contractID=cont.contractID 
    and cont.Duration='5 Months' and p.planType='RM59/month'
    cust.custID=b.custID and b.status='pending'
```

Comment: it need to have 10 columns with 2 attributes of each of the 5 tables.